# How do you check if this function $f(x) = |x-2| - 1$ is continuous and differentiable on the interval $[1,3]$?

Tags: calculus

I need to check $f(x)$’s continuity and discontinuity on $[1, 3]$ to perform mean value theorem. I don’t see how I can turn it into a piecewise function to perform such a thing since there aren’t any end points for that.

Comment: Express it as piecewise function, one piece when $1 \le x<2$ and the other when $2 \le x \le 3$

Comment: It is not differentiable at $x=2$. You can tell that by the argument in the absolute value. It is piecewise continuous, with a sharp change at $x=2$. You can even plot the function if you want to double check.